# How to overlay an activity with another

Tags: java, android, google-maps, layout

Well, I have a map activity like this:

[Map activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa9tK.jpg)

When I click in the marker's infowindow, it opens a new activity with information of that marker... But I wanted to achieve something like this:

[My goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baNMh.jpg)

I want to slide the second activity with information over the map, how could I do that?

Comment: You could use a `DrawerLayout`

Comment: you can make right side drawer layout for this.

Comment: or use this https://github.com/wunderlist/android-sliding-layer-lib

Comment: I found Pravin's solution very easy to use, I'm using it right now... Ty'all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain it more expecificately? You have tu use [Fragments](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj5iJrRi-nPAhXJtRQKHdvXDLUQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fguide%2Fcomponents%2Ffragments.html&usg=AFQjCNHVdjk9-eHwHjiZgaq9Qubc8fcEpA&sig2=dSwN4VxqddSuTSRh2xQpvw) and I recommend you to use a [Navigation Drawer View](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiF-6i4jOnPAhWIbxQKHcB5DTUQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Ftraining%2Fimplementing-navigation%2Fnav-drawer.html&usg=AFQjCNE7eA8B3oLVWooYCq0x4GZ2E89_dA&sig2=Wpubut0IyNvxeF1vZzi6vg).